# How can I prove nlog_2 (n) is O(n^1.01)?

Tags: big-o

The question is f(n)=n^1.01, g(n)=n*log2(n), prove g(n) is O(f(n)). I am not sure how to do it, can anyone explain it? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a software or programming problem. You may be able to get help on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to take the ratio n log n / n<sup>1.01</sup> and take a look at what happens as n tends toward infinity. The limit of the fraction n log n / n<sup>1.01</sup> as n tends toward infinity is

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (n log n) / (n<sup>1.01</sup>)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> log n / (n<sup>0.01</sup>)
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (1 / n) / (0.01 n<sup>-0.99</sup>) *(via l'Hopital's rule)*
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> n<sup>0.99</sup> / 0.01n
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> 1 / 0.01n<sup>0.01</sup>
>
> = 0

This means that n<sup>1.01</sup> asymptotically dominates n log n, and so n log n = o(n<sup>1.01</sup>).